# X11 confusion with windows/solaris/windows config

Tags: x11, windows, solaris, vnc

I am struggling with X11 forwarding ....

I use a Windows 7 laptop to Putty onto a Sun T2000 running Solaris 10.
I have got ssh -> X11 -> X11 Forwarding ticked but nothing in the the X display location box..... apparently we don't need it....

I then use vncviewer on the T2000 to get to a Windows server , but get

VNC Viewer Free Edition 4.1.3 for X - built Dec  3 2008 23:11:23
Copyright (C) 2002-2008 RealVNC Ltd.
See http://www.realvnc.com for information on VNC.
X connection to SATURN2:10.0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).

My understanding is I'm trying to Display back to the T2000, not the Windows 7 laptop so therefore shouldn't need Xming or similar. Or is that wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted. I downloaded Cygwin and eventually got it going. From there I used `startx` and ssh'd on from there.... works pretty well so far. I'm looking into getting Exceed 9 and trying that out too

Answer (score 1):

If you tick X11 forwarding in PuTTY it will try to display on your windows machine. VNC viewer on the Sun machine tries to open that display via X.

I am not sure what you want to achieve, but if you want to start an X based program without it displaying on the Windows machine you want to look at [xvnc](http://www.realvnc.com/products/open/4.0/man/Xvnc.html). Once that is running you can (optionally) run vncviewer from your Windows machine and connect to `xnvc`

Comment: ah.... sorry I'm new to this site and not really familiar with the processes here ..... let me have a think....

Comment: I'm trying to display the Windows GUI on the remote server back onto my laptop.... but go in via a Solaris box. Is the Solaris box irrelevant as Putty (with X11 Forwarding set) is being run on a Windows laptop?   Another fella here has a Windows desktop machine and it works on there, albeit V....E....R....Y.... slowly. He gets a window opening up on his workspace.

Comment: Sorted. I downloaded Cygwin and eventually got it going. used `startx` and ssh'd on from there.... works pretty well so far. I'm looking into getting Exceed 9 and trying that out too. Thanks for the pointers.